# Smoothing edges of contours

Tags: python, opencv

I have a set of images where every image looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, some edges of both external and internal contours are jagged:

[image]

It's importnat to note that protruding parts're always 1 pixels thick. I'd like to smoothen all the edges by either removing protruding parts or filling gaps between them.

Here's a desired result (filling gaps approach):

[image]

Are there any contour-wise or pixel-wise techniques for such a task?

I know that blurring is widely used for smoothing but I vaguely understand how it can be applied to my case. For example, here's median blur in action:

```
image = cv2.imread('source.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
median = cv2.medianBlur(image,3)
thresh = cv2.threshold(median, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

The result looks the same as the source image. No changes.

Comment: What has stopped you from just trying the blurring method?

Comment: [Morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) perhaps? It's not clear to me what the end result should look like. Are wider protrusions (10 px or wider) fine or do you want to remove/fill them all?

Comment: I would try a median filter. If it's one pixel then a 3x3 should work.

Comment: Check each row, ıf the pixel value equal to 255(white), begin to count. If it hits 0 value(black), and if that counter is less then make that row black. Same for columns also

Comment: @gnodab I updated my post. I've tried to use median blur, but the result is the same as my source image.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk, sounds like you're suggesting to fill every black pixel between white pixels. Could you elaborate on the "counter" comparison, please?

Comment: I think yunus has a great suggestion. Median filter may have been the wrong idea. You might could get a [rank_filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rank_filter.html) to work. But you may need to think carefully about the’footprint’